# How to get previous value in depth buffer?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, depth-buffer

How I can to do the next algorithm? :

```
if(Color.a < 0.9)
    gl_FragDepth = gl_PrevFragDepth;
else
    gl_FragDepth = gl_FragCoord.z;
```

This I can make with 
`glDepthMask(false);`, but it's working with polygons which have all pixels with `alpha < 1`. If polygons have pixels with `alpha = 1` and `alpha < 1` I have incorrect rendered picture. I need this to rendering text masks, which contains any alpha values!

I can't use depth texture because I need to real-time working with depth buffer!

Answer (score 0):

> How I can to do the next algorithm? :

In OpenGL-4 you could do it using depth texture writes in the fragment shader. But the performance will be horrible, because GPUs are optimized for gather access, not scatter access, which however is what you're trying to do.

With OpenGL-3 and below you can't do it. Sorry.

Comment: but what about rendering to depth texture only... and then reading it in the next pass?

Comment: @fen: That would work, but the OP specifically said, that he can't or don't want to use multiple passes.